# Stucked while making a splash screen. Unknown error

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-debug

```
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
Debug service listening on ws://127.0.0.1:55743/-QUEMI0IafA=/ws
Syncing files to device Android SDK built for x86...
I/zygote  ( 6057): Do partial code cache collection, code=15KB, data=19KB
I/zygote  ( 6057): After code cache collection, code=15KB, data=19KB
I/zygote  ( 6057): Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
I/flutter ( 6057): build
D/EGL_emulation( 6057): eglMakeCurrent: 0xb2c0cd80: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x95c6d3c0)
```

I am making a splash screen it is working fine but suddenly the error occurs.
The error is in the last line.

Comment: how are you generating/making slash screen?

Comment: Please Upload your splash screen activity.